# Where is the directory for openERP on mac OS?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, openerp-8

I am installing openERP following the manual in [1]: http://netbeam.in/blog/install-openerp-on-mac-osx/

I execute the next command:
tar tvfz openerp-7.0-latest.tar.gz

Before is supossed that I will execute:
sudo mv openerp_XXXXXX to home directory
cd openerp_XXXXXXX

But I don´t know where is the path of openERP is installed.

Can you help me to end installing openERP?

I am use Mac OS Yosemite.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

openerp is still inside the directory you extracted in step 6 (`tar tvfz ....`), but that directory is still located in your Downloads directory which isn't a good place to stay.
So they instruct you to move the openerp directory to your home directory: `sudo mv openerp_xxxxxx /Users/<your-username>/` should be the right command. After that, the next command should be `cd /Users/<your-username>/openerp_xxxxxx` to go to the moved directory.

Comment: Hello @cello 
The problem when i execute:

tar tvfz odoo_8.0-latest.tar.gz 

is that i obtain a lot of lines type 

drwxr-xr-x  0 root   root        0 18 nov 02:02 openerp-8.0-c7d8e97/ 

but when i search the directory i can not find it. Thanks!!!

Comment: it should be wherever you execute the command. Type `pwd` to see in which directory you currently are. Based on the `root root` output, it looks like you're running the whole thing as root (which you probably shouldn't!) and as such are in a directory normally hidden in the finder. But just doing `sudo mv openerp_xxxx /Users/<your-username>/` should move it to a place you can see and access it

Comment: I typed pwd and obtain /Users/benjaGarrido/Downloads but i can not find the directory openerp-8.0-c7d8e97 to move at the proper path. :(